# Changing Permalinks for Category Pages Only

Tags: categories, permalinks

I am working to redesign a site and would like to rework the permalink structure for the category pages only. Right now they are using:

```
/category/category-name
```

I would like to switch this to:

```
/category-parent/category-name
```

When doing this though, I don't want to change any of the post URLs that are currently `/year/month/post-name`. Is there a way to change the category permalinks, but not the post links?

A few comments too:

- I know I will likely have the restructure the categories to be in parent/child form, since they currently are not.
- I thought about using custom post types, but I would rather not do that since it doesn't seem like the best use here.

Comment: Did you play with the optional settings yet if not try that. Location: Settings > Permalink

Answer (score 0):

is rare, but it would have to default as you run you want. This forces the operation that you need

```
function my_category_link( $termlink, $term_id ) {
  $term = get_term( $term_id, 'category' );
  $ancestors = get_ancestors($term_id, 'category');
  if( !count($ancestors) ) return $termlink;

  $hierarchical_slugs = array();
  foreach ( (array)$ancestors as $ancestor ) {
    $ancestor_term = get_term($ancestor, 'category');
    $hierarchical_slugs[] = $ancestor_term->slug;
  }
  $hierarchical_slugs[] = $term->slug;
  return home_url( user_trailingslashit(implode('/', $hierarchical_slugs), 'category') )."\n";
}

add_filter( 'category_link', 'my_category_link', 9, 2 );
```

to restructure the categories:

[Assign parent category to all posts that are already assigned to child category](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/133627/assign-parent-category-to-all-posts-that-are-already-assigned-to-child-category/133637#133637)

Comment: thanks. I assume I just paste that into my theme's function.php file? When I do that it seems to restructure the permalinks for just the categories, which is perfect. They all lead to a page that outputs a 'Post not found' error even though I know there are posts that have those categories. Anything I am missing?

Comment: hey @ Andrew, Test / wp-admin/options-permalink.php in the "Base Category" put "." unquoted

Comment: @ Salem, I am not sure I understand. Are you wanting me to edit the options-permalink.php file? I thought you never really wanted to change core wp-admin files. Maybe I am misunderstanding though. Thanks!

Comment: no, from the manager. from url http://example.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php

Comment: http://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/remove-category-base-from-permalinks ... sorry, my English is very bad because translate.google use